# How to mount volumes on kubernetes using emptyDir

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume

I am trying to create a deployment out of my kompose file, but whenever I try:

```
kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml
```

I get the error:

```
Volume mount on the host "[file directory]" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
```

I have tried a few different solutions to my issue, firstly trying to add `hostPath` to my `kompose convert` as well as using persistent volumes, however both do not work.

my kompose files looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes emptyDir
    kompose.version: 1.7.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: es01
  name: es01
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: es01
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS
          value: "1"
        - name: COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
          value: elastic_search_container
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms7g -Xmx7g
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
        - name: node.name
          value: es01
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.1
        name: es01
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: es01-empty0
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: es01-empty0
status: {}
```

I am using kompose version 1.7.0

My Docker Compose version:

```
version: '3'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=elastic_search_container
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms7g -Xmx7g"
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
    ulimits:
      nproc: 3000
      nofile: 65536
      memlock: -1
    volumes:
      - /home/centos/Sprint0Demo/Servers/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - kafka_demo
```

Comment: What you posted is what it looks like after conversion, what about before

Comment: Did you try creating that Deployment object and spinning up a pod? It may actually work from volume mount perspective as the configuration seems OK. According to some posts om the Internet (if you can trust them), the message from kompose can be safely ignored.

Comment: What version of kompose are you using?

Comment: I am using kompose version 1.7.0

Comment: Can you provide the part of docker-compose.yaml with volumes section?

Comment: @DawidKruk I just updated my question with my docker compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look on warning you get:

```
Volume mount on the host "[file directory]" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
```

It happens when volume in `docker-compose.yaml` is configured with direct path.

Example below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "./storage1:/test1"
      - "./storage2:/test2"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
volumes:
  storage1:
  storage2:
```

#### Persistent Volume Claim

Take a look on this link: [Conversion matrix](https://kompose.io/conversion/). 
It describes how `kompose` converts Docker's volumes to Kubernetes ones.

Executing the conversion command without `--volumes` parameter:

`$ kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml`

With `kompose` 1.19 output will yield:

```sh
WARN Volume mount on the host "SOME_PATH" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host 
WARN Volume mount on the host "SOME_PATH" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-service.yaml" created   
INFO Kubernetes file "redis-deployment.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-deployment.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-claim1-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created
```

Warning message means that you are explicitly telling `docker-compose` to create volumes with direct path. By default `kompose` will convert Docker's volume to [Persistent Volume Claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#persistentvolumeclaim).

#### emptyDir

Executing the conversion command with `--volumes emptyDir` parameter:

`$ kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml --volumes emptyDir`

Will yield effect:

```sh
WARN Volume mount on the host "SOME_PATH" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host 
WARN Volume mount on the host "SOME_PATH" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-service.yaml" created   
INFO Kubernetes file "redis-deployment.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-deployment.yaml" created
```

`kompose` will create [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) declaration inside web-deployment.yaml instead of creating separate definitions of PVC as it has in default.

#### hostPath

Executing the conversion command with `--volumes hostPath` parameter:

`$ kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml --volumes hostPath`

Will yield effect:

```
INFO Kubernetes file "web-service.yaml" created   
INFO Kubernetes file "redis-deployment.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-deployment.yaml" created
```

As you can see there is no warning about not supported path. There is no warning because it created [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) explicitly using your own provided paths from `docker-compose.yml`.

Take a look on `web-deployment.yaml` volume section:

```
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /LOCAL_PATH-/POD_PATH/storage1
        name: web-hostpath0
      - hostPath:
          path: /LOCAL_PATH-/POD_PATH/storage2
        name: web-hostpath1
```

Comment: whenever I run ```kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml --volumes hostPath``` it throws an error that states: ```FATA Unknown Volume type: hostPath, possible values are: persistentVolumeClaim and emptyDir```  I am using kompose 1.7.0